# Excel slow to calculate after clearcontents

Tags: excel, vba

Just wondering if there is something I can do to get around this issue. I'm using Excel 2019

I have a spreadsheet of over 100K lines in column A which holds sorted number values. I use this formula in column B to count the numbers that are the same: =IF(A1<>A2,COUNTIF($A1:A$1,A1),"$$$")

When I initially open the workbook and copy the formula down in colB it doesn't take to long to process. However, if I then select colB and select clearcontents it takes forever to accomplish this task (about 5 minutes).

Once it has completed. If I add exactly the same formula again to B1 and copy down, it now takes forever to process the data. Whereas when I initially did this on first opening it was really quick. Why?

BTW clearcontents was just an easy way to demonstrate the issue. What I am actually doing is Copy and Paste to save the data and remove the formulas.

Is there an alternative VBA code that I could use to replace the formula, which would save having to use copy/paste?
Example:

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of counting the occurrences for each value?

Comment: The IDs in col A are user IDs, so it's counting how many times each user has had data written against them. Therefore if ID 1 appears appears 5 times in column A I need it to show the count in col B and so on for each ID in column A

Comment: Your formula is not counting the number of occurrences of each id, it is doing a kind of ranking of each ID. To count the occurrences of the ID's, you could use something like =COUNTIF($A:$A$100000, A1) depending on your row range. Maybe you could share a file with columns A and B, so that we can look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to say, I can not see your intent! Did you consider using a pivot table to get the total per ID?

Comment: Do you know any VBA code that could replicate the formula in col B, i.e. to count the number of same IDs in column A??

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Sub FormulaColumnB()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim idRng As Range: Set idRng = ws.Range(Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    
    ' Formula column B
    idRng.Offset(0, 1).Formula2R1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>R[1]C[-1],COUNTIF(RC1:R1C[-1],RC[-1]),""$$$"")"
    
    ' copy to values
    idRng.Offset(0, 1).Copy
    idRng.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
    Application.CutCopyMode
End Sub
```

Comment: That is just replicating the formula. What I was hoping for is a method that just performs the counts and saves the answer directly in column B without using a formula.

Comment: Just needed to be converted to values!  Code updated.

Comment: Its the copy and paste element of the code that is the problem. The actual formula works very fast. I was hoping to be able to use a VBA script that would provide the result without having to use a formula, but it seems that might not be possible.

Comment: What do you mean with "Its the copy and paste element of the code that is the problem"? Is there any problem with the code I posted? Is it to slow?